# show that $0\le \frac a{1+b}+\frac b{1+a} \le 1$

Tags: inequality

Let $0\le a < b \le 1$

prove that $0\le \frac a{1+b}+\frac b{1+a} \le 1$

This is the answer from book :

Obviously $0\le \frac a{1+b}+\frac b{1+a}$ so :

\begin{align}
&1\ge \frac a{1+b}+\frac b{1+a} \\
\iff & (1+a)(1+b) \ge a(1+a)+b(1+b)\\ 
\iff & 1-a^2\ge b^2-ab \\
\iff &(1-a)(1+a)\ge b(b-a) \tag{*}
\\ \iff & 1+a\ge b-a
\end{align}

which is obvious.  Q.E.D.

But I can't understand how we get last inequality from $(*)$.

Comment: I don't see it either, although I'll keep looking for a while. Also isn't it considered a bit cringe to use "obvious"? Whenever I use that word in writing a proof or an answer to a question it comes back to bite me in the ass...

Comment: May I know which book is it?

Comment: @adam it's not so hard too show the last one is correct ;but I agree whenever you use "obvious" you'll miss score.

Comment: @ArcticChar actually it's not a latin book it's in "Persian" and it's a famous one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $0\le a , b \le 1$

We prove that $$0\le \frac a{1+b}+\frac b{1+a} \le 1$$

Let $$F=\frac a{1+b}+\frac b{1+a}$$
Then $F\ge 0$, note that
$$\frac{a}{1+b} \le \frac{a}{a+b}$$
and
$$\frac{b}{1+a}\le \frac{b}{b+a}$$
Adding the last two we get
$$F\le 1$$
Equality holds when $$a=1=b.$$

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is a typo, they meant to say

$$ 1-a \ge b-a,$$

which is true from

$$ (1-a)(1+a) \ge b(b-a)$$
since $1+a \ge 1 \ge b$.

(Of course, $1-a\ge b-a$ is the same as $1\ge b$)

Comment: I see and one more question. Which site is better to learn latex commands? e.g. "begin" that you edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

An easier proof for me is the following:

Firstly, $\frac a{1+b}+\frac b{1+a}\geq \frac{b}{1+a}>0,\ $ as numerator and denominator of $\frac{b}{1+a}$ are both positive.

Secondly,

$$\frac a{1+b}+\frac b{1+a} = \frac{a(1+a)+b(1+b)}{(1+b)(1+a)} = \frac{a+b+a^2+b^2}{a+b+ab+1}. $$

So if we show that $ab+1 \geq a^2 + b^2, $ and then we are done. To this end:

$$\text{Since } b>a,\ \text{ and } a\geq 0,\ ab \geq a^2.\quad \text{Also, } 1\geq b, \text{ and so } 1 \geq b^2.$$

$$\text{Therefore, } ab+1 \geq a^2 + b^2.  $$

The strict inequality holds on the left side only:

$$0 < \frac a{1+b}+\frac b{1+a} \leq 1.$$

Equality on the RHS occurs when $b=1$ and $a=0.$